# gwt check if jre is installed

Tags: gwt, java

I have a simple java applet that is invoked from gwt application. Is there a way to check the GWT code if jre is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach to check JRE installation in GWT is no different from the same check using JavaScript/HTML. You should write a JSNI ( http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html ) function, which will execute JavaScript logic to determine JRE availability.

First result from the search is this article, which may however, not cover all possible browsers, but is a good start anyway.
http://www.javatester.org/enabled.html